# Zero-effort off topic

Tags: discussion, feature-request

We have a close reason for 'home audio' but we don't have one for the 'what's this [link] ?' questions with absolutely zero effort, zero use to others ... ever.

This is the latest in a long line of them recently.
[anyone know the name of sfx? (in vdo clip from TH)](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/42944/anyone-know-the-name-of-sfx-in-vdo-clip-from-th)
He couldn't even be bothered to type in whole words.

It's not like knowing the name would even help.
It serves no-one but the OP.

Honestly, they're so useless as a resource for this site [or any other] I find it hard to even be bothered to think up a custom 'close reason' when I VTC.

Could we possibly come up with some stock wording at least, that I can just copy/paste into this garbage as a VTC?

Otherwise we're in danger of going the same route as [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions), which I've stopped even looking at.

We've got space for more customs, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked and we can add another one.

I'd suggest using wording similar to one of Music's close reasons:

- Questions about identifying or finding a particular sound effect from an audio or video file, are off-topic since they are rarely useful to future readers.

Comment: It can't come soon enough :/ https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/42949/hi-i-would-like-to-know-if-you-could-assist-in-determining-what-the-given-sound

Answer (score -1):

I like Rory's proposed new close reason, but I'm wondering if there are additional aspects we could roll into it, to cover real zero-effort as well as 'what's this link?'

I like the wording used by Ask Different...

> questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research &
>   understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a)
>   clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it
>   or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either
>   case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

...although clearly a straight copy/paste of that wouldn't quite work.

Comments welcome on tweaks/proposed merges of the two most welcome.

I'm hoping, if we only have one additional custom message, we can use it to lump a whole swathe of useless questions into it.

Comment: The reason I don't necessarily agree with this is that I think people should be able to research on here.  If we have something that is truly useful to others but hasn't been covered, I want it to be asked and answered, even if it's easy to find the answer elsewhere.  After we answer it the first time, we can VTC dupe.